# Named anchor in a Single Page Application (SPA)

Tags: html, single-page-application, sammy.js

In a SPA, using a navigation framework such as Sammy.js, how could I use in page named anchors for in-page navigation?

e.g. Say I have a route like `localhost/myapp/#/somerecord/1` where the application loads *somerecord* with id = 1.

However *somerecord* is really complicated and long. I want to be able to jump to a certain section using a named anchor.

Say an article element is defined like `<article id=section-d> ... </article>` and I just link to like `<a href=#section-d>Section D</a>` it technically works, but the URL reads like `localhost/myapp/#section-d`, this breaks the navigation stack. Hitting the Back button takes me back to `localhost/myapp/#/somerecord/1` and *without* jumping back to the top.

The preferred action would be to either jump back to the top or to the previous page. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10113103/829970, but that one only has bad answers (i.e. answers for plain Javascript without sammy.js).

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351231/scroll-to-anchor-link-in-a-sammy-js-project

Answer (score 3):

Effectively, you have to define your URL as a regular expression, and allow an optional bookmark hash at the end of it; something like:

```
get(/#\/somerecord\/(\d+)(#.+)?/, function() {
    var args = this.params['splat'];
    var recordId = args[0];
    var articleId = args[1];
});
```

This should match any of the following routes:

- #/somerecord/1
- #/somerecord/1# (treated as if there is no article id)
- #/somerecord/1#section-d (articleId = '#section-d')

You should then be able to use the articleId to find the matching element and manually scroll. e.g. in the last route above, using jQuery you could do something like:

```
var $article = $(articleId);
    $(document.body).animate({ scrollTop: $article.offset().top });
});
```

I've just written up a more comprehensive article about this (using Durandal), if you're interested: http://quickduck.com/blog/2013/04/23/anchor-navigation-durandal/

**Edit**
Link is dead. The article available here http://decompile.it/blog/2013/04/23/anchor-navigation-durandal/

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem using durandal with sammy.js. Basically, you have to create a (invisible) route for each anchor you want on your page. See a post from me about the solution I found: http://papamufflon.blogspot.de/2013/04/durandal-scrollspy.html